# How to add google maps to android studio kotlin project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I'm using android studio version: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
Language kotlin.

I have already google maps api key.

What I did so far was creating empty new project activity and then I did File > New > Google > Google Maps Views Acitivity

Then according to the documents, I created a new file secrets.properties to add my api key to that file.

For creating the file I selected the app then right mouse click then: New > File > secrets.properties and then added this line:

GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=my api key is here already

Then in the file build.gradle.kts (app) I tried to implement the reference to the api key from the secrets.properties file.

This is the file content:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.liveroute"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.liveroute"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        // Load the secrets.properties file
        val secretsProperties = Properties()
        val secretsFile = rootProject.file("secrets.properties")
        if (secretsFile.exists()) {
            secretsFile.inputStream().use { secretsProperties.load(it) }
        }

        // Set your Google Maps API key as a build configuration field
        buildConfigField("String", "GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY", "\"${secretsProperties.getProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY")}\"")

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

but now I'm facing two problems:

1. Properties() not exist at line 19.
2. I can't see anywhere under app on the left side window the new created secrets.properties file.  I tried to make Expand All but the file is not shown anywhere.

I followed the documents.

Here is a screenshot now I can't see also the file MainActivity.kt when I click on the file I see the path app > src > main > java... but I can't find any src under app.

not sure what is going on.

[where is the mainactivity.kt under app ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsK24.jpg)

same happens with the secrets.properties file:

[secrets.properties do not list under app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj1ti.jpg)

and I tried already to do File > Sync Project with Gradle Files but it didn't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api key goes to local.properties file. Put it inside double quotes.  Please confirm that the file doesn't go in version control.